# Proposal for mass-migration from StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange, migration

I'm going to propose that we request for a mass-migration from StackOverflow here, specifically, any question which has one or more of these tags, and no other tags not listed here,

- `[terraform]`
- `[terragrunt]`
- `[ansible]`
- `[chef-infra]`
- Kubernetes

  - `[kubernetes]`
  - `[k3s]`
  - `[kubectl]`
- `[semantic-release]`
- `[semantic-versioning]`
- `[docker-swarm]`
- Cloud providers

  - `[amazon-web-services]`
  - `[azure]`
- `[continuous-integration]`
- `[continuous-deployment]`
- ci

  - `[gitlab-ci]`
  - `[github-ci]`
  - `[jenkins]`
  - `[travis-ci]`

If we'll accept it. Or, if the mods accept it assuming no one will answer here. I can propose it to SO and SE.

Comment: Great suggestion! I would say we could expand that list further as well, but that is a great start!

Answer (score 1):

I don't care too much.  I know most of this is on topic over at StackOverflow and ServerFault somewhat, but I don't necessarily get answers to my questions there either.

Technically, this should be a better place to ask DevOps related questions.

---

Sorry, re-read your post, you want a mass migration *to* this site?  Well that would be a nice jumpstart - and probably justify the splunk advertising dollars. The last person to suggest something like this suggested we can devops.stackexchange.com.

Please, by all means ask for it!

Comment: Has this been done with ServerFault before? Are certain topics migrated to that site as well?

Comment: As a note, questions can be on-topic on multiple sites. A question that's on-topic on Stack Overflow should not be migrated to another site (such as this one), even if it is on-topic on the other site as well. Migration would only be potentially justified if the question is *not* on-topic for Stack Overflow but *is* on-topic on the other site. I'm no expert on the scope of either site, but such questions would first have to be disallowed on SO for them to even consider migrating them here.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be a bad move.
Most of these tools are related to Sys-admin or developer roles. So they might be better on StackOverflow or ServerFault.

"DevOps" is more related to culture and organization. This was well said in [another answer](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/348/6162):

> methodological questions, culture questions, questions on management of change, DevOps mindset, applying DevOps techniques to various parts of the value stream, to various businesses, etc.

It would be unfortunate if we have e.g. two sites for developer tooling (since it is also on-topic on StackOverflow). The same for sys-admin and cloud like `ansible` and AWS infrastructure, it is on-topic on ServerFault and it would be unfortunate if we split it on more sites.