# What kinds of question are on-topic here? (The Help Center is currently silent)

Tags: feature-request, off-topic, help-center

At the time of this writing, the [`/help/on-topic`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for the main site seems to only contain cookie-cutter text about what other network sites might be suitable for questions that are off-topic here (the section that starts with "*If your question is not specifically on-topic for this site, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site.*")

Perhaps there are other network sites that are also like this, but for me, this is the first site I've encountered where that Help Center page is completely bare of actual particular guidance on what kinds of questions/topics are on-topic for the site.

I'm not a contributor to this site and I'm not familiar with its topicality or subject matter. I just came to notice this when writing an answer to a question Meta Stack Overflow: [Proposal for updated guidance for [kubernetes] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423039/11107541).

Is there a particular reason for this? If I may humbly ask, could you please put this as a high-priority item on a to-do list?

I've seen different "types" of `/help/on-topic` pages. Ex. One interesting type is [the one on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), which starts with a broad category and then chops off a bunch of things. I wonder what approach is suitable to writing this Help Center page for this site.

I think this is important to do because now whenever I want to try my hand at contributing to a Stack Exchange network site, the first thing I do is look at `/help/on-topic`. The question that echoes in my mind here is "If I don't know what kinds of questions are on-topic, how can I have confidence that a question I want to ask is on-topic?".

Possibly related: [Proposal for mass-migration from StackOverflow?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/38667).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the site is as cut and dry as the definition of devops.

Which is to say, not very.

It's probably easier to say what devops isn't.

It is isn't logging in and fixing something.

What does that leave?

- All the tools and platforms that help with fixing things with a layer of abstraction between you and the thing you're fixing so that you can get things done efficiently and at scale are topical.
- Every public or private cloud platform thing is going to be topical.
- Anything that helps with CI/CD pipelines is topical.
- Anything that automates deployments or configuration is topical.

I think we have to contact the community managers to update that page, at least I've never updated it on the sites I moderate. If someone wants to start a CW page for things that are on topic (which is a more complete list than this - I don't think it should contain any specific technologies though) I'd be willing to get that page updated

Comment: For a start, it would be good to know whether this site is about [DevOps (the concept/methodology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) or about [DevOps (the Microsoft Azure software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps). This is currently left completely open by the "on-topic" page. Then, in the former case, it is not at all clear whether e.g. questions about tools to help with DevOps, about the behaviour of people applying DevOps, or the history of the science behind DevOps would be on-topic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the only thing I'd definitely exclude are subjective-style questions.